# Is the SAGA tool Basic terrain analysis included in Processing?

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-processing

I can't find the saga tool Basic terrain analysis in the Sextante/processing toolbox. Is this not included or is there a chance to install it?

Comment: Or is there a chance to use this saga modul via python script?